# How to fix RewriteRule RewriteMap syntax

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, rewritemap

I am writing a multi-site platform and currently using the following in my virtualhost/.htaccess

```
RewriteMap sitemap "txt:/home/fb/multimapper/map.txt"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /home/user/public_html/multimapper/sites/${sitemap:%1}/$1 [L]
```

I want to put the trailing slash (/$1) within the rewrite rule so I can add a universal 404 page (before anyone asks: I don't want to use multiple ErrorDocument 404 entries - it's not feasible for this project).

So adding 404.php...

This: `${sitemap:%1}/$1 [L]`

Becomes: `${sitemap:%1/|404.php?catch=}$1 [L]`

EG.

```
RewriteMap sitemap "txt:/home/fb/multimapper/map.txt"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /home/user/public_html/multimapper/sites/${sitemap:%1/|404.php?catch=}$1 [L]
```

Problem is, `${sitemap:%1/` fails. Even if I backslash `${sitemap:%1\/`

Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: Did you mean `${sitemap:%1|/404.php?catch=}$1` ?

Comment: Hi Capsule. No. I want to redirect to either /home/user/public_html/multimapper/sites/%1/$1 or /home/user/public_html/multimapper/sites/404.php?catch=$1
- I do not want the slash in 404.php?catch=/$1

Comment: Well, you'll have to find another way because you can't have that `/` next to `%1`, but what you could do is add it to your every entry of your map.